# error in TurtleBot2

Tags: turtlebot2, turtlebot, ubuntu, ubuntu-precise, base-odometry

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,guys. I have big trouble.....in TurtleBot2.
When I launch rviz, TurtleBot2 rotations itself........but in fact it is not rotation......
This is video: [Turtlebot2 error](http://youtu.be/bYaklkvUeXo)

I use groovy in ros and Ubuntu 12.04LTS 64-bit.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/173325/error-in-turtlebot2......./) by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on ROS Answers with karma: 62 on 2014-06-10

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [FfoNy](https://answers.ros.org/users/4511/ffony/) on 2014-06-11**:
I found the problem........
"/odom" has problem but I have no idea to solve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looks like you have the same problem as zenifed. Check the first answer; updating kobuki firmware should fix the problem.

http://answers.ros.org/question/160561/turtlebot-navigation-hydro-drifting-orentation/#172632

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2014-06-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1